# one to many attributes nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form that creates a league and 10 teams for that league. I am having trouble setting up the back end to do this.

Right now I have this hitting my backend:

```
 Parameters: {"league"=>{"name"=>"League Name", "teams"=>[{"name"=>"Team 1"}, {"name"=>"Team 2"}, {"name"=>"Team 3",...]}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works.

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :teams
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams
end
```

And in **LeagueController:league_params**, whitelist the nested attributes. Note that its **teams_attributes** that is whitelisted and not **teams**

```
def league_params 
     params.require(:league).permit( :id, :name, teams_attributes: [ :id, :name ] )
end
```

Make sure the following param structure hits the code. Note the change from ***teams*** to ***teams_attributes***

```
{"league" =>{"name"=>"League Name", "teams_attributes"=>[{"name"=>"Team 1"}, {"name"=>"Team 2"}, {"name"=>"Team 3"}]}}
```

*The code is not tested so may need tweaking.*